# Fixing requirements in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, apache2, php, symfony-2.1

I've made a Symfony2 installation on my machine.

When I check the requirements in my local url:

```
localhost/Symfony2/web/config.php
```

It says:

> MAJOR PROBLEMS
>
> Set the "date.timezone" setting in php.ini* (like Europe/Paris).
>
> RECOMMENDATIONS
>
> Set short_open_tag to off in php.ini*.
>
> Set magic_quotes_gpc to off in
>   php.ini*.
>
> - Changes to the php.ini file must be done in "/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini".

I've made the required changes both in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`:

> date.timezone = "Europe/Madrid"
>
> short_open_tag = Off
>
> magic_quotes_gpc = Off

Both `short_open_tag` and `magic_quotes_gpc` where already set to Off when I checked the php.ini files.

After that I've restarted apache2:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

However I still get the same error messages.

I use Symfony 2.1.2, Ubuntu 12.04 and PHP 5.3.6

**UPDATE**:

If I run phpinfo() from the browser, it says the Loaded Configuration File it's located in:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

If I run `php -i | grep php.ini` it says the Loaded Configuration File it's located in:

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

These are the two files where I've already made the changes.

I've made sure that the changes have been saved in the file. I also have used phpinfo() in a php file and executed it in the browser. It says that the values for date.timezone are not set, and magic_quotes_gc and short_open_tag are set to On.

If I execute `php app/check.php`, the requirements are resolved, so I suppose that `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` it's working correctly and there is only a problem with `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`, which is the one that works with the browser.

Comment: run `phpinfo()` from browser or `php -i` from terminal and find which `php.ini` file is being used. Maybe apache is using some other? And since you wrote you have two `php.ini`'s maybe it would be more reliable would be to run `phpinfo()` from browwser...

Comment: I've updated the question with this info.

Comment: For me, it was that I was using php-fmp, and just restarting apache with `service apache2 restart` wasn't enough to reload the php.ini file.  I had to issue a `service php5-fpm restart` also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The changes you have made should fix your problem if done correctly; double check that. Make sure the changes are actually being saved. Many times when I edit php.ini files in Ubuntu I forget to run the editor with the right permissions(root) and miss the warning that the file could not be saved. Also, verify the changes by calling phpinfo() from a script.

Do you get the the same result when you run the scrip located in app/check.php from the terminal. From project root:

```
php app/check.php
```

If still having problem, all I can suggest is clearing the cache; with symfony2 a lot of problems are solved that way.

Comment: You said that you checked phpinfo() and changes are not reflected, can you somehow post your php.ini file or a screenshot.

Comment: I had a syntax error in my php.ini, however it didn't prevent apache from restarting, so I didn't notice before. I located it in the log file: /var/log/apache2/error.log. 

Now all works fine.

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to remove the comment semi colon from the beginning of the string also from /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

From :

```
;date.timezone = "America/Vancouver"
```

To:

```
date.timezone = "America/Vancouver"
```

Comment: It's embarrassing, but have to admit you solved my problem. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

I too had to set the date.timezone variable in response to the same error message.
The error message was finally resolved by clearing the cache as below by running:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you editing correct ini file ?
I'm edit /etc/php5/cli/php.ini and that resolve problem for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. When you have enough reputation, you may leave comments asking for clarification, but until then, remember that only answers should be posted in the answers section.