# Apache and Symfony date.timezone error

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I am trying to install Symfony with my Apache (Ubuntu) but I get this error:

```
Set the "date.timezone" setting in php.ini* (like Europe/Paris)
```

Using `phpinfo()` in my browser it says that the configuration file is in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` So I modified it wtih

```
date.timezone = "Europe/Paris"
```

I also modified the file `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

I also run php `app/console cache:clear` as it was suggested in this question [Fixing requirements in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999221/fixing-requirements-in-symfony2) but with no results. I restarted the server every time.

What else can I try?

Thanks!

Comment: how about `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`?

Comment: did you restart apache2 after you changed the config file?

Comment: Yes, also `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` I made a mistake in the question. I modified this php.ini too

Comment: I restarted with `sudo service apache2 stop` and then start. Is this a restart? I am new to apache on ubuntu (worked previously on windows)

Comment: php -i | grep 'Configuration File'

Comment: In sf1, I ran through this and got it fixed with a date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid') in the bootstrap (that was ProjectConfiguration.class.php). Would by any chance a similar trick work for you ? (in sf2 you may modify the web/app.php file, I think).

Comment: When I run `php -i grep 'Configuration File'` I get this `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

Comment: @mika yes mika, Thanks, it worked now. You can put your comment as an answer for those who have the same issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Please see David Jacquel correct solution below !**

I leave this answer for historical purposes...

In sf1, I ran through this and got it fixed with a

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
```

in the bootstrap (that was ProjectConfiguration.class.php).

In sf2 you may modify the web/app.php file to insert the same piece of code. It is a bit hackyish, but will get you up and running.

Comment: Actually, @DavidJacquel's answer below is the correct one !

Answer (score 4):

Try removing double quotes

```
date.timezone = Europe/Paris
```